# Continuous and Inverse function

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I need to prove that if $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $X$ and $Y$ are closed and bounded, then if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and has a inverse function, than the inverse function is also continuous.
In the previous exercise I was asked to show that if $f$ has a inverse function, the inverse function is continuous $\iff f$ sends open groups to open groups $\iff f$ sends closed groups to closed groups, This I've shown, and I should probably use it for this exercise, but I didn't find a way to use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are closed and bounded(which is necessary)

Thanks!

Comment: groups = subsets, I suppose?

Comment: What have you proved about closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ specifically?

Comment: Yes, groups means subsets.

Comment: We learned that a sub-space of a complete normed vectoric space is a complete metric space if and only if it is a closed group, and we learned that all the norms on R^n are equivalent

Comment: Nothing about sequences and the existence of convergent subsequences?

Comment: We learned it at calculous, but just in R, but we proved that a sequance of closed groups with diameter going to zero converges into one single point if and only if the metric space is complete. In calculous we proved Blozano-Weirstras through this lemma, maybe they expect me to do the same here?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are - as bounded and closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively - *compact Hausdorff spaces*.

In such spaces a set is compact if and only if it is closed. If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $F\subseteq X$ is closed then $F$ is compact so that $f(F)\subseteq Y$ is compact as well. The next conclusion is that $f(F)$ is closed. So apparantly $f$ is a closed function, i.e. sends closed sets to closed sets. A continous and closed bijection (i.e. a map that has an inverse) is a homeomorphism. Its inverse will also be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hi, thank you but we did not learn in the course about Hausdorff spaces and compact groups, but from what I understood you are using a theorome which is more general, can you try to prove this specific case without the more general theorome? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm..., it is beyond doubt that there are persons here who can do that. I posed this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1755146/75923) on this. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks! you might want to add the fact that this question has a previous exercise, which is to prove that if f has an inverse function, than f is an open function if and only if f is a closed function if and only if f^-1 is continuous

Comment: I think persons who react will find that out automatically. This because they will have a look at your comments following the link in my question.